# Image not updated in browser window

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I'm using node, javascript and HTML bundled with electron.

I'm downloading an image from the web using a random image API and then saving the image as bg.jpg then setting this as the background of the body. This is all in a `setInterval()` that executes every 10 seconds.

The image downloads and successfully overwrite the old one each time but in the browser window it does not apply to the new image to the body's background - it only happens the first time round. I can't seem to figure out what is happening but it seems as though the old image is never updated in the browsers resources.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    request = require('request');

var download = function(uri, filename, callback){
  request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
    request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
  });
};

function getPhoto() {
    download('https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random', 'bg.jpg', function() { 
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(bg.jpg)";
    });
}

getPhoto();
setInterval(()=>{
    getPhoto();
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Do you need to download the image? How about pointing the css at the remote image?

Comment: Unfortunately I do as I will be eventually doing other stuff with the image that will need it stored locally.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caching issue, can you try?

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url(bg.jpg&ts=${Date.now()})`;
```